# Missing values in R data frame

Tags: r

How does R handle missing values with respect to the context below and missing values?

I'd be very grateful if anyone has a link to documentation explaining what R is doing in the below example and why.

Many thanks

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
b<-c(11,NA,NA,14,15,16,17,18)
c<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
d<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,NA,8)
mydf<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)


> mydf
  a  b c  d
1 1 11 1  1
2 2 NA 2  2
3 3 NA 3  3
4 4 14 4  4
5 5 15 5  5
6 6 16 6  6
7 7 17 7 NA
8 8 18 8  8


>mydf[mydf$b>11,]

      a  b  c  d
NA   NA NA NA NA
NA.1 NA NA NA NA
4     4 14  4  4
5     5 15  5  5
6     6 16  6  6
7     7 17  7 NA
8     8 18  8  8
>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit annoying. When `NA` is on either side of `==`, `<`, `>`, etc., the result is always `NA`. Try running `mydf$b>11`. You'll see you get `FALSE    NA    NA  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE`. If you subset a data frame with `NA` in place of a logical (i.e., `TRUE`/`FALSE`) value, it will produce `NA` as the result.

To get what you probably want, you want `mydf[!is.na(mydf$b) & mydf$b>11,]`, which only produces the rows in `mydf` where `b` is not `NA` and is greater than 11.

Note this site is not the appropriate site for asking non-statistical computing-related questions like this one. For that, go to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: "`mydf[!is.na(mydf$b) & mydf$b>11,]`, which only produces the rows" this should produce column without `NA`, not rows. Am I right?

Comment: No, it produces rows. The logical vector comes before the comma in the brackets to index rows. The code is exactly the same as your but with an extra logical condition (the `is.na` part). Since your code selects rows, so does the code I presented. Also, you can try it yourself on the data and see what it produces.